# How get the names of templates where a template is included in Symfony/Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a partial template in twig that I include in different templates of my application.

*partial.html.twig*

```
<p>My partial template</p>
```

So for example I can use this template in another template:

*my_template.html.twig*

```
<% include partial.html.twig %>
```

My goal is to somehow get all the template names where the *partial.html.twig* is included, dynamically.

Is this possible ?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but why in the world would you want this?

Comment: @Stratadox I want to create a menu where the user can select a "place" to display something. Those "places" are checkboxes that I want to be dynamic

Comment: Dynamic is fine, but it's a bit of a buzzword so everyone means something else by it. Those dynamic checkboxes are, with extreme probability, representing important concepts in your domain. If I were you I'd model them as, well, domain models. That will give you much more control over who can go to which places and what a place represents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also (like Stratadox) have my doubts if this is exactly what you should go for, but in any case if you have to get all the templates where `partial.html.twig` template is included, you could use Symfony Finder Component like this:

```
// App/Controller/DefaultController.php
public function foo(){
    $templatesDir = $this->get('kernel')->getProjectDir() . '/templates';
    $finder = new Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder();
    $finder->files()->in($templatesDir)->contains("{% include 'partial.html.twig' %}");
    $templateNames = [];
    foreach ($finder as $template) {
        $templateNames[] = $template->getFilename();
    }
}
```

Now you can do whatever you want with these names.

Of course you have to deal with issues like double and single quotation marks when including the `partial.html.twig` or comments that include this string without really include the template (not so probable case).

You can handle this problem (especially with the quotation marks) by using a suitable regular expression instead of a string as argument to the `contains()` function of `$finder`.